# How to re-assign/name the argv in main

Tags: c

To re-name the args in main, I do the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char * strings[argc];
    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) strings[i]=argv[i];
}
```

Out of curiosity, why wouldn't something like the following work instead:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char * strings[argc] = argv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because in C, an array cannot be initialized with another array. This has nothing to do with `argv` or `main`. Here's a simpler example of the same problem:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};

int b[] = a;  // error
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. Why isn't that allowed in C out of curiosity? Is there a way to copy over an array, for example with memcpy or something else in C? Basically, what's the easiest way to "clone" an object in C, or does it always need to be done manually?

Comment: You have to ask the people who made C, that's a tough question. Note that if you wrap the array in a struct, you _can_ copy it.

Comment: Could you please show an example in your answer of how you can copy it with wrapping it in a struct?

Comment: Of course you can notice that array lvalues "decay" (to a pointer to the first element), and generally initializers aren't lvalues, and so there's no lvalue conversion for arrays, but that's really just replacing one question with another.

Comment: `struct foo { int a[3]; }; struct foo x = /* ... */; struct foo y = x; /* copy array */` https://godbolt.org/z/HMroOO